# Most accurate GPS hardware for less than 1 mile radius

Tags: gps, development

I apologize if this is a duplicate but I can't find a good answer or area to know where to find the correct answer.

I am looking for the technology or hardware around wearables or similar technology that can detect movement or at least log location within about a 2 foot area.  I have looked around at it looks like the most common devices use triangulation but aren't more accurate than around 400 feet.

Is there any tech that is more specific than a two foot radius?  I am not trying to waste anyone's time but I can't find a better place to get an answer....

Comment: The term you're looking for sub-meter accuracy. However, your requirement of *movement* within a 2' radius makes me wonder if you're really looking for accuracy or if what you actually want is precision (of course they are related). Accuracy is where you are, precision is where a recorded point is relative to another recorded point. There's [another question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97644/what-sub-meter-geolocation-solutions-exist-and-how-can-i-integrate-them-into-a-w/97759#97759) where someone has suggested a Kickstarter for a unit that has centimeter level precision.

Comment: @ChrisW Good point, you are correct that precision is probably the correct measurement.  Thanks for helping to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common entry-level GPS has an absolute precision of roughly 40 feets, but there are many "tricks" that help improving this precision. For instance, you can collect several points of the same position and average this position (which is not a good solution if I understand well your case) or you can use WAAS enabled GPS. I see that you live in the States, so you can expect 3 to 4 feet accuracy with the WAAS in 95% of the cases with relatively cheap hardware (200$).

If you want better, then you should look for DGPS RTK systems, which are clearly more expensive but will allow you to reach from 2 feet to a couple of inches in terms of accuracy. You will then need to have data from a second receiver, either from publicly available data if your area is covered, or from yourself. The prices will then be completely different. See for instance the Leica or Trimble Websites for models.

Comment: If you are developing something yourself I suggest to read the FOSS-GPS mailing list archives.